# Extract data from script tag [HTML] using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, session-cookies

I want to Extract data from a variable which is inside of a script:

```
<script>
var Itemlist = 'null';
var ItemData = '[{\"item_id\":\"107\",\"id\":\"79\",\"line_item_no\":\"1\",\"Amount\":\"99999.00\"}]';
</script>
```

I want the `item_id` and the Amount inside of a variable in python

I tried using regex it worked for a while but when the cookies session updated it stopped working

Is there any other way to get those values??

I am using this method to get the script from the html but it changes when the cookie session updates

```
soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script')[8]
```

so i have to change the number that i've put after `('script')` for now it's `[8]` if cookies session updates i have to keep changing the number until i find the script i am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data from the `<script>` you can use this example:

```py
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_data = """
<script>
var Itemlist = 'null';
var ItemData = '[{\"item_id\":\"107\",\"id\":\"79\",\"line_item_no\":\"1\",\"Amount\":\"99999.00\"}]';
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("script").text
data = re.search(r"ItemData = '(.*)';", data).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

print("Item_id =", data[0]["item_id"], "Amount =", data[0]["Amount"])
```

Prints:

```
Item_id = 107 Amount = 99999.00
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the HTML has multiple scripts
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: @AceDasXan Of course, you need to select correct `<script>` tag. Or try `re.search(r"ItemData = '(.*)';", str(soup)).group(1)`

Comment: I tried using that but getting this error:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

The code that I am using:
`response = requests.get(link, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
html_data = response.content

soup = bs(html_data, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("script")[-4]
print(data)

data = re.search(r"ItemData = '(.*)';", str(soup)).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

print("Item_id =", data[0]["item_id"], "Amount =", data[0]["Amount"])`

Comment: @AceDasXan Without seeing the real HTML data/URL is hard to tell where is error.

Comment: so i printed the `re.search` and found that the script that i am directly pulling from the link has "\" while the `script` that i typed manually into the `html_data` doesn't, so i think i have to get rid of "\" right?

Comment: I added this line `data = data.replace("\\", "")` after `re.search` and now it's working, thanks